# revocation vs. suspension

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is the word  **Revocation** is same as **Suspension**

Which of the following sentence sounds natural and correct.

> Tampering with system date and time settings would result in **Revocation** of your 30-day trial license.
>
> Tampering with system date and time settings would result in **Suspension** of your 30-day trial license.

Can i use permanent suspension?

Comment: Can i use **permanent suspension**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're not the same. The term *revocation* generally is synonymous with the word *annulment*. For example, when the government revokes somebody's passport, they're making it void which means that it no longer "counts" as an official document. For all intents and purposes, it simply does not exist as a legal document and thus can no longer be used as such. When it comes to the digital world, the revocation of something like a license for a piece of software means exactly the same thing—you can't use it because it's no longer legally applicable.

*Suspension*, on the other hand, means that your account or whatever it is that you're talking about is temporarily blocked. Although all the data is still there, it's not going to be accessible by the owner for a specified period of time. And when they unblock you, you get all your data back intact. As for the term *permanent suspension*, it means exactly what it says—that your account is blocked on a permanent basis.

Your sentences sound absolutely fine except that you need a definite article before the words *revocation* and *suspension* and there is no need to capitalized them. And I also think that it's better to use the modal verb *may* instead of *would* in this situation because *would* is usually used for expressing the conditional mood to indicate the consequence of an imagined event or situation while *may* expresses only the potential possibility of something happening which is more suitable for legal language. In other words, *may* just sounds a bit more formal than *would*. So, here are your two sentences improved:

> Tampering with system date and time settings **may** result in **the** revocation of your 30-day trial license.
>
> Tampering with system date and time settings **may** result in **the** suspension of your 30-day trial license.

The last thing that I will mention is that you would probably want to settle on the word *revocation* since software licenses, to the best of my knowledge, are usually revoked and not suspended.

Comment: In regards to your last sentence, I agree. Especially because 30-day trials are already set to expire, so "suspending" them would be odd.

Comment: Hi I just noticed that the last word day**s** in the original sentence was edited to **day**. Is 30-days is grammatically incorrect ?

Comment: @Hole Oh, I didn't notice that either. No, it's not correct. It should be *your 30-day trial*, of course.

Comment: annulment and revocation are not exactly synonymous at least not in all cases. Something annulled may from a legal/contractual standpoint may be considered never to have existed; whereas revoked means only has ceased to exist.

Answer (score 4):

[**Revocation**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revoking)

To revoke:  to officially cancel a decree, decision , or promise.

> The judge **revoked** my driver's license.

[**Suspension**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suspending)

To suspend:  to temporarily take away a privilege or to prohibit (someone) from holding their usual post or carrying out their usual role for a particular length of time

> They have **suspended** the peace talks.

The key difference between the words is that of permanence.

A "suspended" driver's license means your license is temporarily out of service. It will be reinstated once the suspension period ends.

A "revoked" driver's license means your license has been fully canceled and cannot be reinstated.